# The better way to solve a Google Maps markers filter problem

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

I need filter items on map (GOOGLE MAP)

filter by range distance like Tinder to show only items near from origin point

like a 30 KM radius

Any item in my database have LATITUDE / LONGITUDE and also full address

What the better and faster way to filter and show these items on Google Map

I already have the distance in KM between two coordinates using the Google Maps API and also Haversine Formula

What is the better way to filter and return items filtered to add the markers to map?

OPTION A: Is better create a function in PHP (Laravel) to filter on the server-side and return by API those items to Ionic APP?

OPTION B: Is better get coordinates from API and then create a function in Ionic APP to return filtered items on the client-side to show on Google Maps?

OPTION C: Or you can suggest another idea better?

Please, someone, can help me?

I Know is a simple question
But my fear is when this project grow and have a lot of items to filter and as a result, need much time to filter and return items to Google Map

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider saving the data as a `point` data type.

```
$table->point('position');
```

MYSQL have basic geometry support, so then you could query it to find only points inside a bounding box or by any other geometric operation you would like.

Also, check out this repo: https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial where you can see a section `scopes` explaining how to query it.

Comment: Thanks, I will be taking a look in your tip

Comment: Only Works with recent Mysql version, MariaDB still don't have this function